# tvos: UIViewController does not receive touchesBegan

Tags: swift, tvos, touchesbegan, first-responder

I am trying to write an App for Apple tv4 (tvos). When my App  starts, the *view controller* does receive `touchesBegan` events, as it should.

Without going into too many details, the App creates, moves, and deletes sub-views to respond to the user's interactions.

After a while, the view controller does not receive `touchesBegan` any more (this is the *strange error* that I am trying to debug).

Since I think the problem has something to do with the *responder chain*, I have made the following two experiments:

1. If I let the view controller override and return `true` from  `canBecomeFirstResponder`,   then the problem still occurs, *but it occurs much less frequently*.
2. If I do not override that function and instead check *who is* the first respnder, then I find that the App has no first responder, even before the strange error occurs. That is to say,  the App has no first responder even when it is working properly!

*Questions:* What can prevent `touchesBegan` from being invoked? Is it related to the responder change? If so, please explain 2 above.

Comment: Sorry.. I might have got this wrong... After re-reading, you're saying that it stops working after using it for a bit? Maybe you could provide some more info on exactly what you are doing (including code examples) so we could get a better understanding on what is going on.

Comment: is it possible that you are adding `UIButtons` or other elements that enable the focus engine, therefore disabling the regular touch events?

Answer (score -2):

How exactly are you supposed to "touch" a view rendered on a non-touch screen enabled TV?

You're not.. tvOS doesn't work like iOS in the way that you cannot detect touches because there is no touch screen enabled input device supported on an Apple TV.

Instead, you use the `UIFocusEngine` to handle interactions with content presented within your view hierarchy.

Check out "[Controlling the User Interface with the Apple TV Remote](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html)" from Apple's Developer Library for more information.

Comment: Well, I can touch the Siri Remote (or press the alt-key in the simulator). In addition, I can use gesture recognisers to detect swipes. Everything works fine until the error occurs. Probably, it has something to do with focus/or the first responder.

Comment: an action on the Siri Remote cannot map to a coordinate within a `UIView`. high level APIs such as `UIControl` and `UIGestureRecognizer` have been updated to support this cross-platform (with minor tweaks) however low level stuff like `UITouch` doesn't exist simply because it can't translate. Check out the next section in the link above (Detecting Gestures and Button Presses) as it explains it all. You could technically look at using `pressesBegan:`, `pressesChanged:` etc but its not going to be a direct replacement to the touch equivalent

Comment: I don't care about absolute coordinates. I like to know when the user swipes, and in what direction she swipes. pressesBegan is always invoked, no problem, but I like to capture swipes as well.

Comment: You don't have to care, UITouch does and because of this it won't get called. Maybe look at using `UIGestureRecognizer` instead then.

Comment: Maybe you did misunderstand me. My touchesBegan *is* invoked when I begin run the App, but then  the bug/error occurs. I am also using a *gesture recogniser*.  Both the recogniser and the virtual touchesBegan stops working at the same time.

Comment: Yep, sorry i got it wrong.. My one guess would be that your view loses focus via the `UIFocusEngine`. I haven't listened for the `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:` or `touchesEnded:` events on tvOS myself before (didn't even know they worked ha) so I wouldn't be much help after that.. See my comment on the actual question as well, it might help when getting help from others

Comment: Thanks anyway! *You are probably correct* that one should use the focus engine! Normally, one should not *reinvent the wheel*. But in this case, it took me only one hour to reinvent something equivalent to the focus engine for my App. It does not work because some part of apple's more general  focus engine is swallowing the messages I need.

Comment: Unhelpful answer. Indeed, for common UI interactions, the focus engine is fine. But it's 100% valid to use `touches...` and `presses...` functions on a view controller to evaluate touch events for advanced, custom touch handling. FWIW, I'm observing this same behavior occasionally where it will not receive touch events even though it will continue to receive press events. It feels like a bug with tvOS.

Comment: Update: This was directly a result of the focus engine interfering with some touches. By disabling user interaction on the problematic control, my view controller always fired the `touches...` functions.